# Windows Font Appears Lighter

Tags: windows-10, fonts, cleartype

Since today (perhaps a late reaction to a previous Windows update?), the fonts in *Microsoft Outlook* and in the *Start Menu* (see example below) and *Windows Apps* appear lighter (less font-width) than before. But only in light mode, in dark mode, it looks still the same.

I tried adjusting the Windows Clear Type, and also the Screen Calibration (as mentioned in the comments) but that didn't really solve the issue.

The font in the browser, and Windows Explorer is still correct and good readable.

---

**Font in the Windows Explorer (still good readable):**

[image]

**Here is the new light font in light mode (hard to read):**

[image]

**And here (still good readable, slightly more font-width) in dark mode:**

[image]

**And here is my latest Windows update from 2021:**

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and specify which update was installed today?

Comment: Try adjusting the appearance, e.g. background color. Also note some newer settings in Display, such as "Night light" and HDR color.

Comment: I will try contacting Windows Support today also

Comment: Update: Microsoft Online Support updated the graphics driver, didn't solve the problem either...

Answer (score 1):

I press windows key, then type 'gamma', and one of the suggestions that pops up is "calibrate display" (something of that wording).

It lets you calibrate gamma, but also the style of true type fonts that get shown to your monitor.  Maybe this setting is off for the user in question?

Comment: Why would it effect a single shortcut in the start menu?  At this point the question does not contain enough information to really be answered.

Comment: It helped a tiny bit, setting the gamma a bit lower. But I think the main issue is that the font is too light in terms of widths, than before the Windows update

Comment: Sorry, the user account actually didn't made the difference. It was the setting light/dark mode (which was different for the user accounts). I updated my question accordingly to be clear about this.